# Why can't I call the defined function of model in admin page

Tags: php, yii

The code following doesn't work when it is put in the admin.php file. It seems that the `actionAdmin` doesn't preload the models. How can I fix it?

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'templateset-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        array(
                      'name'=>'disable',
                      'value'=>$model->numberToStatus(),
                ),
        array(
              'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

The function `numberToStatus` is defined as

```
public function numberToStatus()
    {
            $disabled=Yii::t('myExtension', 'disabled');
        $non_disabled=Yii::t('myExtension', 'non-disabled');
        $statusArray=array($disabled, $non_disabled);
        return $statusArray[$this->disable];
    }
```

I have try many methods and failed, Do you have any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use

```
'value' => '$data->numberToStatus()',
```

Comment: Thanks, I read the class reference of CGridView again and find the answers.